# Filesystem change from FAT32 to ext3/4

Tags: debian, filesystems, external-hdd

I'd like to change my HDD extension filesystem from FAT32 to ext3/4. Is it possible to make it with use of terminal and without data loss? I use Debian (stretch).

Comment: In-place?  Not really.  Best to move the data off of the partition, destroy the old partition, create the new one, and move the data back.

Comment: @DopeGhoti i'd do so if it wasn't over 500 Gb

Comment: @Cnoob there is [this tool](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform) to go from one these filesystems to another `ext2, ext3, ext4, jfs, reiserfs, xfs`. It does however have a lot of risks. You can also upgrade ext2 to ext3 and ext3 to ext4 with little risk. What you are asking for is not really possible without reformatting. You will need to backup the data and reformat the drive if you are going from fat32 to anything else.